# Reflectivity of mirror?

Tags: reflection

Is mirror displaying the original image. Is there a constraint for the reflective property of mirror. Does mirror reflect with 100% perfection?

Comment: You question is far too wide-open to be answered usefully.  Can you try to define what you think "correct" and "100% perfection" mean?  Color match? Distortion of image? Loss of light intensity?  and so on.

Comment: Most mirrors are aluminum second-surface mirrors, which have an average reflectivity in the visible range of roughly 90%. So yes, there is loss.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I take major exception to your claim of "most" . Maybe most consumer-grade home use mirrors are, but there's rather a large number of applications which use significantly different materials.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: True, although the OP seemed to be referring to home-use mirrors.

Comment: Related: [Is a Perfect/Lossless Mirror possible?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112122/is-a-perfect-lossless-mirror-possible). See also [a perfect mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_mirror) at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

> Does mirror reflect with 100% perfection?

No mirror will have 100% reflectivity, there will always be some absorption.

This can be applied for most ideal objects, since perfection does not exist.

> I doubt that am i seeing the correct reflection of myself?

I don't understand this part.

Comment: which means am i seeing my same color etc through a mirror, eg when you take a photograph it may look more perfect than what i see myself in mirror..

Answer (score 1):

An electrically conductive first surface mirror cannot be as efficient as a multi-layer first surface dielectric mirror.  The reflection mechanisms are different - absorption and re-emission vs. optical resonance.

What is a "correct" image?  If you want high fidelity return, use a fused silica corner cube operating via total internal reflection.  Do you want to reverse intermediary optical aberrations?  Use a phase conjugate mirror.  Viewing your face in a phase conjugate mirror will be a spiritual experience.

Don a pair of circularly-polarized 3-D movie glasses, then look in mirror.  Close one eye,  Whoa!  What will be the result of closing both eyes?

Comment: PCMs are certainly fascinating... You say "viewing your face in a phase conjugate mirror will be a spiritual experience." Can you elaborate? I'm not sure what I would expect to see. Illuminated with coherent monochromatic light? Passing through a distorting or scattering medium? Would it look interesting just to stare into a "bare" PCM? What would you see? I don't have access to one (and may never have), so I'm curious if you know.